# Selenium Testing unable to target element

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am running some testing on our website using selenium.
At the login page I would like to target the login button and click it.

the source code of the page looks like this:[image]

I am trying to target the second button that has the `class=OTSigninButton` by using its xpath.

so here is the python code.

```
time.sleep(5)
element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div/svg[2]/path')
element.click()
```

but when I run the code I get the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div/svg[2]/path"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.106)
```

Here is the weird part. The login page has 2 buttons, their xpath is similar as its a list.

the first button is:

`//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div/svg[1]/path`

and the second button(the one I want to target) is

`//*[@id="root"]/div/div[1]/div/svg[1]/path`

As both of them has the `id=root`, if I `find_element_by_id` and target root, I am able to click on the first button.

Here is where I am struggling a lot, how can I use the xpath to target the second button?

thank you so much for your time and help guys.

EDIT: Full error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and contains(@class, 'OTSigninButton')]/title")
  File "/Users/<user>/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "/Users/<user>/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "/Users/<user>/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Users/<user>/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[local-name()='svg' and contains(@class, 'OTSigninButton')]/title"}
  (Session info: chrome=91.0.4472.106)
```

Comment: can you share a link to that page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class=OTSigninButton
```

is a attribute of `SVG`.  These are special tags, you can not just write their tag name in console and locate them.

try this instead :

```
//*[local-name()='svg' and contains(@class, 'OTSigninButton')]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I tried to do as you said `element = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[local-name()='svg' and contains(@class, 'OTSigninButton')]/title")` but I am getting the same error.

Comment: What is the error ? Please share entire error stack trace

Comment: Problem solved. I had to remove the `/title` Thank you so much mate. you are a rockstar